# Not capturing the line needed with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to search for the class 'student-login' from the URL https://www.champlain.edu/current-students. I then want to further search within that class and return the complete line(s) if it contains either the string 'username' or 'password'. My working code returns everything within the class but I am having no luck enhancing it to get the specific lines only containing 'username' or 'password'. I have included a screen capture of my current output. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('https://www.champlain.edu/current-students')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
soup = bs.find(class_='student-login')

print(soup)
```

[image: Current ouput]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract? The input fields?

Comment: Hi @skrat. Yes. I want the entire <input id line(s) that contain either "username" or "password".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the input fields:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('https://www.champlain.edu/current-students')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

print(bs.select_one('#login-username'))
print(bs.select_one('#login-password'))
```

This is using CSS selector, the `#` in front means you're selecting any element with the id = login-username which I assume is what you want.

Comment: Thanks @skrat, that worked great! 

I had one more question. Is there a way to just search a specific class for #login-username and #login-password instead of the entire website?

Comment: Yes @zeusbella you can change the selector string to `.student-login #login-username` the dot prefix means class, and stuff after it must be "descendant" of it. You can learn more about CSS selectors here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors . Also note that the element ID should be unique in a page, so you shouldn't have to be more specific than that. You can also right click on an element in browser and select Inspect, it will open a DOM inspector. In it your element will be selected. If you right click it, go to Copy > Copy selector (Chrome)

Comment: Thanks @skrat!! for the additional example and link! I have some more reading to do regarding CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of variety, you can use `find()`. Because the tags that you are looking for have unique `id` attributes you can find them directly:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('https://www.champlain.edu/current-students')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

username = bs.find(id="login-username")
password = bs.find(id="login-password")

>>> print(username)
<input id="login-username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
>>> print(password)
<input id="login-password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
```